# Does this sentence need a comma?

Tags: commas

I want to convey that Trevor Cunningham also sometimes goes by the name Tre Cunn.

A) Trevor Cunningham also goes by the name "Tre Cunn" professionally.
Or
B) Trevor Cunningham also goes by the name "Tre Cunn," professionally.

thanks

Comment: I would say that the one without the comma is better. Even if you use the comma it should be after the second set of quotation marks.

Comment: Commas always go inside quotation marks, not after.

Comment: @ d.c.t According to one set of 'rules'. Not, apparently, the ones BoldBen uses. People should avoid pontificating on issues where there are different equally valid conventions.

Comment: @BoldBen That's where I'd put matrix punctuation after a title quote, but isn't there still the contrary style?

Comment: You can also say “Trevor Cunningham (professionally, Tre Cunn) is . . . or “Trevor Cunningham, also known, professionally as Tre Cunn, has been . . .

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't see what the functon of the comma is when it's inside the quote marks. It's almost as though more text is expected before the quote marks are closed.

Comment: I can't see how 'All of a sudden' or 'by and large' work, but I use them. The strangely-arranged terminal punctuation after quotes is apparently a hangover from the practice printers found worked best mechanically.